# Using regex in C program to check password strength

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am writing code in C program to check for the strength of password using regex.
My requirements are:
"atleast one upper character and one lower character one digit and one special character and overall password length should be minimum 9 characters"

First I figured out regex combination in http://regexr.com/ and regex combination is `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[_+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"']).{9,})`

But if I try the same in C language using program below it does not work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<regex.h>

static void  check_password_strength(const char *password) {
    regex_t comp_ex;
    int rc = regcomp(&comp_ex, "((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[_+-.,!@#$%^&*();\/|<>"']).{9,})", 0);
    if (rc != 0) {
        char errbuf[1024];
        (void)(regerror(rc, &comp_ex, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf)));
        printf("%s: error compiling regex: %s", __FUNCTION__, errbuf);
        return;
    }

    if (regexec(&comp_ex, password, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
        regfree(&comp_ex);
        printf("Password accepted :%s\n", password);
        return;
    }

    printf("password NOT accepted\n");
    regfree(&comp_ex);
    return;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("invalid number of args \n");
        return;
    }
    check_password_strength(argv[1]);
}
```

Do I need to use regex in different way in C program? Like `[[:alnum:]]` or `[[:digit:]]`?
Can you please give an hint here if you know?

Comment: "atleast one upper character and one lower character one digit and one special character" That's not how you make a strong password. That's how you make a forgettable password. Don't do this.

Comment: I don't think a regex is a good way to go about analyzing the password. All else apart, you need to allow the different character classes in any order, which is fiddle at best.

Comment: Try to double up each `\ ` (backslash) inside the pattern. Although I agree that regex is not the way to go for this, you can simply scan the string and count each requirement...

Comment: Yet another instance where people inappropriately try to use regular expressions for every string-processing task.

Comment: This is a terrible indicator of password strength. There are plenty of open source password checkers out there that can do a much better job (e.g., [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn)). I suggest you use one of those instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your program didn't even compile. As one of the comment said, you should escape each back backslash character `\`, as it is used by C to special characters. Replace `\` with `\\`, and replace `"` with `\"`, try this escaped regex:

```
int rc = regcomp(&comp_ex, "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[_+-.,!@#$%^&*();\\/|<>\"']).{9,})", 0);
```

Also it is not a good idea to use regex for this kind of checks, just scan the string and count:

```
static bool check_password_strength(const char *password) {
    const char *p = password;
    char c;
    int nupper = 0;
    int nlower = 0;
    int ndigit = 0;
    int nspecial = 0;
    while (*p) {
        c = *p++;
        if (isupper(c)) ++nupper;
        else if (islower(c)) ++nlower;
        else if (isdigit(c)) ++ndigit;
        else if (ispunct(c)) ++nspecial;
        else continue; // space character
   }

   return nupper && nlower && ndigit && nspecial;
}
```